# Why W3C CSS Validator showing parsing error on "Ends-with" Attribute Value Selector

Tags: css, w3c-validation

Why W3C Validator showing parsing error on this. I selected CSS3 profile also from dropdown.

```
a[href $=.xls]{background: transparent url(ms-excel-icon.gif) left top no-repeat;
padding-left: 22px;display: block;height: 16px;}
```

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/347107/11042455758-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/347107/11042455758-My-Desktop.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have a [nearly identical example](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) up on the W3C site

```
a[href$=".html"]
```

with the only difference being that there's no white space between the attribute name and the constraint type and the constraint itself is in quotes.

Comment: still showing error after using this `a[href$=.xls]{background: transparent url(ms-excel-icon.gif) left top no-repeat;
padding-left: 22px;display: block;height: 16px;}`

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: In that case I have no idea, it looks like they have a nearly identical example on the site `a[href$=".html"]`.  Maybe try putting it in quotes?

Comment: Keep in mind that the W3C CSS validator, like all software, occasionally presents bugs. (not saying this is one, but you should be aware :p)